# Calculating the roots of a quadratic with complex coefficients

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, quadratics

$x^2-(5i+14)x+2(5i+12)=0$

I got :

$\frac{(5i+14)+(75+100i)^{1/2}}{2}$

and

$\frac{(5i+14)-(75+100i)^{1/2}}{2}$

Wolfram gives : 2 and 12+5i

How do I reduce my solutions?

Comment: $75 + 100i = 25(3+4i) = 5^2(2+i)^2$

Comment: While Achille has a right observation, generally the quadratic formula for such equations is not the way. It is better to use the method of completing the square, where your equation becomes (after substitution) of the form $z^2=a+bi$ which then becomes straight forward.

Comment: One approach is to take the solution $2$ and divide through the original to get the alternate solution.

Comment: @abiessu True, but what if you do not know any solutions to begin with?

Comment: imran I don't understand...

Comment: @Astroman See my answer...

Comment: That is a weakness in that approach.  It depends on seeing one solution so that the other can be found from it...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general approach:
$$x^2-(5i+14)x=-10i-24$$
$$(x-2.5i-7)^2=-10i-24+(2.5i+7)^2$$
Let $z=x-2.5i-7$ We get: $z^2=18.75+25i$ after working out right hand side. Now this equation ought to be standard to solve. Backsub $z$ for $x$ gives you the 2 solutions.

Comment: What did u do in the second part ? How did you factor the left hand side ?

Comment: For completing the square, you take "half" of the linear coefficient and add the square on the right hand side. This is the basic technique for completing the square. I did not factor. Here is a tutorial from Khan academy if that helps: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/quadratics/solving-quadratics-by-completing-the-square/v/solving-quadratic-equations-by-completing-the-square It's getting late here, I am off to bed...

Comment: Ok thanks ! good night

Comment: Sorry Imran, I understand the completion part but after that I don't see how to solve $z^2$ Could you developfor me pls ?

Comment: @Astroman This question is not quite related to the question you posted. OK, one way is DeMoivre. The other way here is to set $z=a+bi$ and substitute: $a^2-b^2+2abi=18.75+25i$ Separating real and imaginary parts and simplify leads to two equations: $$a^2-b^2=18.75$$,$$2ab=25$$ When you write the second equation as $a=25/(2b)$ and put in the first one, you get after simplification $4b^4+75b^2-625=0$ This is a quadratic equation in $b^2$ which you can solve with the quad formula. I want you to verify that this leads to $b=2.5$ and $b=-2.5$ which leads to $z=5+2.5i$ and $z=-5-2.5i$

Comment: Ok, Im going to try this and give you back news

Comment: Ok, so I got b= + or - 2,5 and b= + or - 5i

Comment: By the way, shouldn't it be the inverse ? z=+ or -2.5 + or - 5i

Comment: Since $z^2$ is in the first quadrant, I know that $z$ has to be in the first  and third quadrant.

Comment: I don't understand what to do next

Comment: once you have the two z-values, plug them back in $z=x-2.5i-7$ and solve for $x$

Comment: Ok, I found this :  z=+ or -2.5 + or - 5i which are 4 values of z

Comment: No, there are two values of $b$ that comes from that quadratic equation. You plug those b-values in $a=25/2b$ and not in $a^2=625/4b^2$ So that gives one $a$ for each $b$ so two combinations, not 4

Comment: Yeah thats what I meant, I got : b= + or - 2,5 and b= + or - 5i

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2-(5i+14)x+2(5i+12)=0 \Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x^2-(14+5i)x+(24+10i)=0 \Longleftrightarrow$$
$$(x-(12+5i))(x-2)=0 \Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x-(12+5i)=0 \Longleftrightarrow \vee\space x-2=0 \Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x=12+5i  \vee\space x=2 $$

Comment: That third line is not something you just see. Finding two numbers that add up to $-14-5i$ and multiply into $24+10i$. You got to be good to see that one coming.....